# I am not able to login in Raspberry pi 3 b+( stretch Os) although my password is correct and I am facing this problem after installing protbuf

Tags: raspbian-stretch, pi-3b+

After installing `protobuf` and rebooting the Pi, I am not able to login into Pi.
The login popup appears, but after entering my password I do not login into the Pi. Also, my password is not showing incorrect.

Looking for help........

Comment: When you say 'not able to login', can you be more specific?  Is the Pi not starting?  Is it starting but not displaying a prompt?  What method are you using?  (ssh, desktop login, etc.?)  Is the password rejected?  Too many possibilities here ...  please provide some details to help narrow down the question.

Comment: `after installing protobuf` I can't see how installing googles protocol buffers could in any way effect your ability to log in - you must've done something else - try starting from a fresh install of stretch

Comment: Not being able to login is usually due to some files in /home/pi not being owned by pi:pi. One way to fix it is to boot to an emergency shell. The other way is a new SDCard with Raspbian and a USB reader. Boot the new system, mount the bad SDCard in the USB reader and repair the damage.

Comment: What does that mean" "*my password is not showing incorrect*". Does the password is shown? And because it is shown correct, why isn't it accepted?

Comment: in login page when I was entering my correct password ....its not popup password error  message ...but is not able to enter ....but if intentionally enter wrong password then it showing  incorrect password